# Чому тут потрібна кома перед "чи"?

Tags: пунктуація

Навіщо в цьому реченні кома перед *чи*?

> Деякі легенди свідчать, що іноді від того, **чи** зможе людина дати
>   правильну відповідь на загадку, залежало її життя.

Comment: -1: Це запитання не свідчить про те, що автор зробив спробу відповісти на запитання власноруч. Ми також нічого не знаємо про джерело, де був знайдений цей фрагмент. Наприклад, це міг бути просто одрук. Але у даному випадку йдеться про підрядне речення, яке позначене комами на початку і в кінці.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Опустимо першу частину речення (до першої коми) для легшого розуміння самої проблеми. Речення, яке залишилося — складнопідрядне з'ясувальне, бо дві граматичні основи (головна — *життя залежало*, залежна — *людина зможе дати*) поєднані сполучником підрядності *"чи"*, а до підрядної частини, що стоїть всередині головної, можна поставити запитання "від чого?".

Отже, підрядна частина складнопідрядного речення виділяється комами.

Comment: Поправив кирилицю у дописі. І ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian.SE!